# C# word interop tables shapes positions

Tags: c#, interop, office-interop

I'm trying to do the following:
Insert an arrow based on the value in a cell in a table.
This part, I have working just fine.
The color of the arrow should be conditional, and works equally fine.

But my problem is this:
How can I identify the correct position to place it.
I have concluded this to 2 problems:

**vertically**: spanning pages. For 1 page, it works, as soon as I try it for the 2nd page, it places the shapes on the first one.
**Horizontally**: the right posistion relative to the text that is entered in the table.

This is the code for the vertical positioning that I have now:

```
private float getVertical(Word.Range r)
    {
        return (float)r.Characters.Last.get_Information(
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage);
    }
```

the code for horizontal(basically add the width of every cel on the same row to 2 thirds of the width of the actual cell)

```
 private float getHorizontal(Word.Range r, Word.Table tab, int col)
    {
        float i1, i2 = 0.0f, i3;
        i1 = (tab.Cell(2, col).Width / 3) * 2;
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < col; i++)
        {
            i2 += tab.Cell(2, i).Width;
        }
        i3 = i1 + i2;
        return i3;
    }
```

any and all suggestions are welcomed and appreciated,

Greetings

ShadowFlame

Answer (score 2):

At long last I have figured it out, and am eternalising(making eternal?) for future reference and documentation purposes :-).

**What I didn't do previously was**: add an anchor range to the shape.
**Where did I find this**: nowhere, had to figure it out by using the MSDN documentation that shapes are linked to anchors, and that if you do not specify, c# will put your shapes on a default range(first page in my case)
**Solution**:(Please note, this is an extract of code, assuming some knowledge of word interop. If any more information is required, do not hesitate to ask.)

```
//create word document  
--some code  

//insert page break here    
--some code   

//insert paragraph  
--some code    

//insert table here
--some code  

//define range  
Word.Range shapeAnchor = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;  

//insert shape  
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType sh =  
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeUpArrow;   

Word.Shape shh = doc.Shapes.AddShape(sh.GetHashCode(), x, y, 
width, height, shapeAnchor);
```

The code that is actually written out can be put into a function, which will then work always.

Greetings,

ShadowFlame